# How to get the first class that a class extends without creating an instance

Tags: javascript, oop

Having a structure like this or similar with multiple levels of inheritance:

```
class Abstract {};
class Concrete extends Abstract {};
class MoreSpecificConcrete extends Concrete {};
class EvenMoreSpecificConcrete extends MoreSpecificConcrete {};
```

I want to know the last class before `Function` that `EvenMoreSpecificConcrete` inherits from.

Comment: Yes, it does inherit from all superclasses? Not sure what else you would expect.

Answer (score 3):

You can recursively go through the prototype chain checking if you ended up at the Function prototype (which every Function extends) and return the last element before this.

```
function getBaseClass(MaybeClass) {
  if (typeof MaybeClass !== 'function') return;

  const Proto = Reflect.getPrototypeOf(MaybeClass);
  return (Proto === Function.prototype || Proto === null)
    ? MaybeClass
    : getBaseClass(Proto);
}
```

You can then compare the returned class with the Abstract:

```
getBaseClass(EvenMoreSpecificConcrete) === Abstract;
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9nLuvyob/

Comment: Or just `getBaseClass(EvenMoreSpecificConcrete) === Abstract` :)

Comment: That being said, if you only want to check whether a class extends a specific other class (not actually getting the parent class), then you can do `EvenMoreSpecificConcrete.prototype instanceof Abstract`. And that would also work for any class in between.

Comment: You're totally right @FelixKling. Thanks for mentioning that!